# protoc-gen-go-grpc: program not found or is not executable

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, protoc

`go version`: go version go1.14 linux/amd64

go.mod

```
module [redacted]

go 1.14

require (
    github.com/golang/protobuf v1.4.0-rc.2
    google.golang.org/grpc v1.27.1
    google.golang.org/protobuf v1.20.0 // indirect
)
```

I am running the following command:

```
protoc -I ./src/pbdefs/protos/ --go-grpc_out=. src/pbdefs/protos/*.proto
```

to generate my GRPC output files from `.proto` files, with I am getting  an error

```
protoc-gen-go-grpc: program not found or is not executable
Please specify a program using absolute path or make sure the program is available in your PATH system variable
--go-grpc_out: protoc-gen-go-grpc: Plugin failed with status code 1.
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

the missing plugin has been implemented at https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go.

command below should fix it

```
go install google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc@latest
```

Comment: it is still unreleased though, subject to change and missing some features.

Comment: @AyushGupta do you a workaround? I had to add this for now, so far it seems ok. may just need to keep on track of any changes

Comment: I'd probably stick with the older version till a stable GA release

Comment: Older version of what?

Comment: @tylerthemiler just stick with `protoc-gen-go` instead of upgrading to `protoc-gen-go-grpc`

Comment: this has worked for me.
here is my requirement
require (
 github.com/golang/protobuf v1.4.2 // indirect
 github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway v1.14.6 // indirect
 google.golang.org/grpc v1.30.0 // indirect
 google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc v0.0.0-20200630190442-3de8449f8555 // indirect
 google.golang.org/protobuf v1.25.0 // indirect
)

Comment: The proposed solution worked for me.

Answer (score 32):

The Golang Protobuf has released a new version of Go protocol buffers which they are calling it as the APIv2.

Because APIv2 is not backwards compatible with APIv1, therefore we will need to adapt all our Golang code for the new API.

You can learn more about the new API [here](https://blog.golang.org/protobuf-apiv2) and [here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf-go/releases/tag/v1.20.0)

**Migration steps:**

In order to run the new code generation will be necessary to install the following gRPC gen plugins:

```
go get -u google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go
go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go

go get -u google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc
go install google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc
```

Then use the following command to generate the code.

```
  # generate the messages
 protoc --go_out="$GO_GEN_PATH" -I "$dependecies" "$proto"

 # generate the services
 protoc --go-grpc_out="$GO_GEN_PATH" -I "$dependecies" "$proto"
```

Comment: `go get` already installs the binaries at `go/bin`. So why `go install` after get'ing?

Comment: @BerkantIpek Because "`go install` [...] is now the recommend way to build and install packages in module mode" and "use of `go get` to build and install packages is deprecated" [since Go 1.16](https://golang.org/doc/go1.16#modules).

Comment: The `go get` seems to be unnecessary if an `@version` suffix is added to the URL eg. `go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go@v1.28.0` 
This version can be explicit `@v1.28.0`, loosely specified `@v1` or `@latest`

Answer (score 17):

If you haven't done, so you need to install the `protoc-gen-go` plugin like so:

```
go get github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go
```

this will install the plugin (if your `GOPATH` is `${HOME}/go`) to:

```
${HOME}/go/bin/protoc-gen-go
```

Then when running `protoc`, either update your path, or set it dynamically like so:

```
PATH="${PATH}:${HOME}/go/bin" protoc ...
```

Comment: I'm tallking about `protoc-gen-go-grpc` not `protoc-gen-go`

Comment: I see, but I've compiled protobuf & grpc with this exact setup. I suspect there's something up with your plugin and/or compiler install. Did you install a precompiled `protoc` compiler or built it yourself?

Comment: I built it myself and it was working fine. I'm trying to upgrade according to [this](https://blog.golang.org/a-new-go-api-for-protocol-buffers) and I start getting the error

Comment: You may be hitting breaking changes with `APIv1` vs `APIv2`. I have not switched to `APIv2` yet. Perhaps using the newer (not github) import path `google.golang.org/protobuf`?

Comment: Yes, using `go get -u google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go` causes the generator to switch to v2, `go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go` is v1

Comment: Found the cause, check my answer

Comment: This was a lifesaver. This answer gave me an idea where the 2 `go install`s placed the bin folder that I have been looking for more maybe an hour now. Also the compiler is a pain in the ass to install right now. Just use chocolatey that that part

Answer (score 15):

OK, just found out, as per https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf-go/releases/tag/v1.20.0

> The v1.20 `protoc-gen-go` does not support generating gRPC service definitions. In the future, gRPC service generation will be supported by a new protoc-gen-go-grpc plugin provided by the Go gRPC project.
>
> The `github.com/golang/protobuf` version of protoc-gen-go continues to support gRPC and will continue to do so for the foreseeable future.

EDIT 29/05/2020:

Following an update from @Mark in the comments, according to the [Tracking issue on github](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/pull/3453), `protoc-gen-go-grpc` has now been merged. However, according to the same issue:

> Even with this merged, it is unreleased (v0.0) and subject to change. We do plan to add a requirement that the Unimplemented service implementation be included in all registered services, with an escape hatch in the form of a command-line arg as suggested by @neild.

Comment: What does that mean. It doesn't answer the question. How and from where would one install `protoc-gen-go-grpc`. Please answer the question and only then mark it as answer.

Comment: @IshanKhare `protoc-gen-go-grpc` is not released yet.

Comment: [protoc-gen-go-grpc](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/pull/3453) has now been merged.

Comment: @Mark thanks for the update. I have added the same to the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Update your PATH so that the protoc compiler can find the plugins:
`export PATH="$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin"`

Answer (score 3):

Share my useful bash command here:

```
go get -u google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go
go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go

go get -u google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc
go install google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc

protoc --proto_path=./proto ./proto/*.proto --plugin=$(go env GOPATH)/bin/protoc-gen-go-grpc --go-grpc_out=./pb 

protoc --proto_path=./proto ./proto/*.proto --plugin=$(go env GOPATH)/bin/protoc-gen-go --go_out=./pb
```

Answer (score 3):

Please check the Go Environment variables by running the `Go env` command on the Terminal and make sure that the following values are set.

GOBIN=some folder location

GOPATH= some folder location

If these are looking good try installing the go plugin

```
go get -u google.golang.org/grpc
```

or run the following on the terminal

```
go install google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc@latest
```

Answer (score 2):

For all who aren't much into the topic (like me) and still have trouble to figure out a working solution, here's a step-by-step approach:

1. `apt install protobuf-compiler` installs the compiler under `apt install protobuf-compiler`, available via `protoc` from then.
2. Install the old go generator plugin to be used by `protoc`: `go get -u google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go` and `go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go`. Also, make sure that the installed plugin can be found in `$PATH` or add it with `export PATH=$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin` if needed.
3. To tell that plugin not only to generate the protobuf message type information but also the grcp methods, use a command like `protoc --go_out=plugins=grpc:my/relative/output/path ./my_file.proto`.

Looks kinda trivial once you've figured that out, but it's quite hard to figure that out if you aren't into that topic and only have scarce information about how the go files generator generator and the grcp extension are supposed to work together.

Comment: Why  `go install` after `go get`?

Comment: @Berkant Ipek Your're right, it should probably be `go get -u`

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for a good answer and finally, it worked for me:

```
protoc --go-grpc_out=. file_path/file_name*.proto
```

Comment: this command solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve a problem in **2022** by finding an answer in a GitHub issue

https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/795

As @neild suggested,
I added both GOPATH and GOROOT to my PATH environment variable by using the command

'export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/go/bin' for GOPATH

'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin' for GOROOT

and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

i solve using this command :

- protoc calculator/calculatorpb/calculator.proto --go-grpc_out=.
- protoc -I=. --go_out=. calculator/calculatorpb/calculator.proto

to generate calculator_pb.go and calculator_grpc.go

```
syntax = "proto3";

package calculator;
option go_package = "calculator/calculatorpb";

message SumRequest {
  int32 first_number = 1;
  int32 second_number = 2;
}

message SumResponse {
  int32 sum_result =1 ;
}

service CalculatorService{
  rpc Sum(SumRequest) returns(SumResponse) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to install all these:

```
go install \
   github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/protoc-gen-grpc-gateway \
   github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/protoc-gen-openapiv2 \
   google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go \
   google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `go get` to download the following packages:

```sh
$ go get github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/protoc-gen-grpc-gateway
$ go get google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go
$ go get google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc
```

This installs the `protoc` generator plugins we need to generate the stubs. Make sure to add `$GOPATH/bin` to your `$PATH` so that executables installed via `go get` are available on your `$PATH`.

Here's an example of what a `protoc` command might look like to generate Go stubs, assuming that you're at the root of your repository and you have your proto files in a directory called `proto`:

```sh
$ protoc -I ./proto \
   --go_out ./proto --go_opt paths=source_relative \
   --go-grpc_out ./proto --go-grpc_opt paths=source_relative \
   ./proto/helloworld/hello_world.proto
```

We use the `go` and `go-grpc` plugins to generate Go types and gRPC service definitions. We're outputting the generated files relative to the `proto` folder, and we're using the `paths=source_relative` option, which means that the generated files will appear in the same directory as the source `.proto` file.

You should check out the tutorial series on gRPC-Gateway, i.e., https://grpc-ecosystem.github.io/grpc-gateway/docs/tutorials/. Also, you can refer to my simple hello world program, which uses gRPC-Gateway, i.e., https://github.com/iamrajiv/helloworld-grpc-gateway.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use https://github.com/storyicon/powerproto to install all protoc-related dependencies (including protoc-gen-go-grpc) with one click and for version control.