# Differences between protoc-gen-go and protoc-gen-go-grpc

Tags: grpc-go

I'm a bit confused about `protoc-gen-go` vs `protoc-gen-go-grpc`. I know that:

- `protoc-gen-go` contains that code for the serialization/deserialization of protobuf messages
- `protoc-gen-go-grpc` contains the code for gRPC Server and Client

But, I'm using the following command

```
protoc -I $protodir --go_out=plugins=grpc:./genproto/ $protodir/v1/foo.proto
```

and the generated `foo.pb.go` contains both code for message serialization **and** for gRPC server/client. Plus that I only have `protoc-gen-go` installed on my system.

I have the feeling that this is the **old-way of doing gRPC in GO** while the **new-way** is with `protoc --go_out=. --go-grpc_out=.`

Questions:

1. why is this working with only `protoc --go_out=.` (why does it also generates gRPC client/server code?)
2. what is the advantage of using one method vs. the other?

Thanks,
DC

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The **old-way** is using the `github.com/golang/protobuf` module. It comes with `protoc-gen-go` that generates both serialization of the protobuf messages *and* grpc code (when `--go_out=plugins=grpc` is used).

The so-called **new-way** is using the `google.golang.org/protobuf` module = a major revision of the Go bindings for protocol buffers. It comes with a different `protoc-gen-go` that no longer supports  generating gRPC service definitions. For gRPC code, a new plugin called `protoc-gen-go-grpc` was developed by [Go gRPC project](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go#grpc-go).
The `plugins` flag, which provided a way to invoke the gRPC code generator in the old-way, is deprecated.

Important note: Users should strive to use the same version for both the runtime library and the protoc-gen-go plugin used to generate the Go bindings.

The longer answer [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60578892/protoc-gen-go-grpc-program-not-found-or-is-not-executable).

Also the [Release Notes](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf-go/releases/tag/v1.20.0#v1.20-grpc-support) explains this.