# Service being generated but not client protoc

Tags: go, grpc, protoc

I am using protoc to try and generate a client / server for my gRPC service.

I have the following in my make file

```
stripe:
    @protoc --go_out=. pkg/proto/stripe/service.proto
```

My proto file is

```
syntax = "proto3";
package grpc;
option go_package = "pkg/proto/stripe/";

service Stripe {
  rpc UpdateVerification(UpdateVerificationRequest) returns (UpdateVerificationResponse);
}

message UpdateVerificationRequest {
  string id = 1;
}

message UpdateVerificationResponse {
}
```

When I run `make stripe` it generates a `service.pb.go` but there is no interface or client generated.

Is this something I am missing in the generation CLI command?

Comment: Try with: `--go-grpc_out=.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [protoc-gen-go-grpc: program not found or is not executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60578892/protoc-gen-go-grpc-program-not-found-or-is-not-executable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `go-grpc_out`, as example:

```
protoc --go_out=. --go-grpc_out=.   pkg/proto/stripe/service.proto
```

Will generate also the `service_grpc.pb.go` file in the same dir of the proto

As suggested in the [quickstart giude](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/quickstart/#regenerate-grpc-code), the full command could be:

```
protoc --go_out=. --go_opt=paths=source_relative \
    --go-grpc_out=. --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative \
    pkg/proto/stripe/service.proto
```