# getting Unimplemented name Error in generated go file from proto

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto, protogen

Every time, I generate the code, I am getting this error:

[image: error-image]

this is my .proto file:

[image: proto-file]

**the command that, I use to generate the code is::**

```sh
protoc pb/pb.proto --go-grpc_out=./pb
```

Comment: You will need both `--go-grpc_out` and `--go_out` options (each option results in an output file per `.proto` and the output from the `--go-grpc_out` argument depends upon the output from the `--go_out` argument). See [the tutorial](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/basics/#generating-client-and-server-code).

Comment: Note: Please [don't post images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) of things like `.proto` files - paste/format the text instead (and for go issues its better to post the output of `go build` rather than warnings in an IDE).

Comment: okay, yeah it's working now

Answer (score 1):

Please try this command to generate the code

```
protoc -I <proto-file-folder/> --go_out=plugins=grpc:<folder-to-store-generated-go-file> <proto-file-folder>/*.proto
```

In your case

```
protoc -I pb/ --go_out=plugins=grpc:pb/ pb/*.proto
```

Comment: The `plugins` argument is outdated and I don't believe it works with recent versions of `google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go` (see notes under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60578892/protoc-gen-go-grpc-program-not-found-or-is-not-executable))

Answer (score -1):

As per [the tutorial](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/basics/#generating-client-and-server-code) you need to use pass `protoc` two parameters; `--go_out` and `--go-grpc_out` (you probably also want to pass the associated `_opt` parameters):

```sh
protoc --go_out=. --go_opt=paths=source_relative \
    --go-grpc_out=. --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative \
    routeguide/route_guide.proto
```

In your case this translates to:

```sh
protoc pb/pb.proto --go_out=./pb  --go-grpc_out=./pb
```

The reason for the error that you were seeing is that `--go-grpc_out` tells `protoc` to run `protoc-gen-go-grpc` (from `google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc`). This executable only generates the gRPC specific code; it assumes that the code required to translate between protoBuf and Go structures has already been created (and this is done by `protoc-gen-go` which is triggered by the `--go_out`).